# Are `P x` and `▸ ((next P) ⊛ (next x))` equivalent in Guarded Cubical Agda?

Tags: agda, cubical-type-theory, cubical-agda, guarded-recursion

In Guarded Cubical Agda there's `▹_ : Set i → Set i`  and `▸_ :  ▹ Set i → Set i`.

If I've got `P : X -> Set` and `x : X`, are `P x` and `▸ ((next P) ⊛ (next x))` equivalent? If so, can it be proved internally or only as a metatheorem? Are there different guarded type theory implementations (Iris, maybe) that would support this?

My thought is that once you know that `x` is the result of `next` and not some fixed-point computation, then the only way to inhabit `▸ ((next P) ⊛ (next x))` is to have a `P x` lifted into it using `next`. I'm still wrapping my head around this guarded stuff, so I might be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not equivalent; `▸ ((next P) ⊛ (next x))` is equivalent to `▹ (P x)`. Hence if it were equivalent to `(P x)`, we would have that `▹ X` is equivalent to `X` for all `X : Set`. The purpose of the filled in modality (which I think of as the "dependent modality") is to apply the later modality to a type that only exists later; in conjunction with the "tick syntax" of Guarded Cubical Agda, this provides a more easily implemented alternative to the delayed substitution syntax of Guarded Dependent Type Theory from the old days.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. So to check, you use ▸ when constructing a non-positive datatype, so that you can transform the `▹ Set` that `fix` gives you into a `Set`, right?

Is there a way to express the idea of "I have  `x : ▹ X`, and a proof that if x terminates (i.e. is equal to `next y` for some y) then `P y` holds? I'm essentially trying to prove something up-to termination

Comment: You can write down such a thing, but I would clarify that "later A" should not be thought of as "an element of A that might not terminate" --- though such a notion can be formalized in terms of the later modality. What you want is the "guarded lift monad", which is the guarded-recursive type given by two constructors: `now : A -> Lift(A)` and `step : later(Lift(A)) -> Lift(A)`. It is worth having a glance at Marco Paviotti's thesis to see what you might do with such a type...